# Is Empty .java file name working?

Tags: java, oop

I started to learn Java couple days ago. And I have this burning question. Is `empty .java` file name a valid source file name?

```
.java
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, save your java file by `.java` then compile it by `javac` `.java` and run by java `yourclassname`

```
    class X {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
```

to compile - `javac .java`

to execute - `java X`

Comment: Wonder why I always thought the .java had to match the class name.

Comment: @djechlin In the case of public non-inner classes it does. It's also the common convention.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's working because java compiler doesn't consider it saves file name or not except our class having public specified we can save any name or empty but when ever trying to execute we must use our class name because, jvm creates byte code `ourclassname.class` so we using

```
java className
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Empty .java file name works, but class must not be public, it means that it must be default.
If class is public then following error occour:

D:\Testjavac>javac .java

.java:1: error: class Empty is public, should be declared in a file named Empty.
java
public class Empty
^
1 error

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can have  .java file withought nay name . you have to compile it by `javac .java`(it compile successfuly) and run it by `java clasnname`.(so you must provide a class name)

Answer (score 0):

*Yes*, but **don't do this often**.

You can't create any classes in that file that are `public` or `private`, so any class that made use of any class defined here would have to be in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

at anytime you can have only one public class in the file and if you use public class then that class name should be the file name.